# PEB structure x64 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, portable-executable, internals

Probably a fairly simple mistake/question as I'm relatively new to C++. I'm trying to query a process's basic information via NtQueryInformationProcess. It all works as expected when using the PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION defined in winternl.h.

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION {
PVOID Reserved1;
PPEB PebBaseAddress;
PVOID Reserved2[2];
ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId;
PVOID Reserved3;} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
typedef PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION *PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

Now, I've tried partially modifying the structure to have a PPEBx64 structure instead of a PPEB with:

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_x64 {
PVOID Reserved1;
_PEBx64 PebBaseAddress;
PVOID Reserved2[2];
ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId;
PVOID Reserved3;} _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATIONx64;
typedef _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_x64* _PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATIONx64;
```

And

```
typedef struct _PEBx64 {
BYTE Reserved1[2];
BYTE BeingDebugged;
BYTE Reserved2[21];
PPEB_LDR_DATA LoaderData;
PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters;
BYTE Reserved3[520];
PPS_POST_PROCESS_INIT_ROUTINE PostProcessInitRoutine;
BYTE Reserved4[136];
ULONG SessionId;} PEBx64;
```

The _PEBx64 definition comes straight from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb

It goes without saying that I could work with the original PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION but I'd like to know, for learning purposes, what am I doing wrong here. There's no error whatsoever but _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATIONx64 fails to load process data(UniqueId is 0, there's no Peb Base Address, etc...)

I'm using:

```
NtQueryInformationProcess(pStartupInfo.hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pProcessInfo, sizeof(_PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_x64), &returnLength);
```

Update:[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZmrq.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't check the function return value then you can't tell that the function failed. 
 The length you pass is essential, the function uses it to double-check that your struct declaration is correct. 
 It is [not](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/giampaolo/psutil/+/master/psutil/arch/windows/ntextapi.h#514)

Comment: @HansPassan Indeed, I now captured the NTSTATUS return value and it's length mismatch(0xC0000004). Nonetheless, I've changed the typedef of the struct to what you've shared and I still get the same NTSTATUS error. Please, see the updated post(added a screenshot there of the results)